# Is there any way to automate the elements inside canvas using webdriveio?

Tags: webdriver-io

We have the canvas element and inside the canvas there are few more elements present and I need to perform some operations on that like click operation etc, however, there are no html tags and attributes present to identify them.

Tried the regular click method by passing the x,y co-ordinates but finding it difficult. Is there any other way we can automate it ?